# Visual Studio UI controls

Tags: windows, forms, user-interface, controls

Hi I've been developing little programs as hobby for the last 3 years and I was wondering if there was a possibility to use controls like in Office 2007+ (ribbon style) and in Windows 7.

I've been looking around the net but didn't found an answer that completely satisfies me. I only found commercial controls like telerik, viblend etc. But isn't there a from Microsoft native UI control pack available? What are my options besides self developing fancy ui controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe DevExpress has ribbon controls. Not sure if they still have it but when I got my license it was for free, has been a few months. You may want to look into that.

--- Found it ---

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/

Comment: I wil try this one and hope that there isn't a watermark on the controls or what so ever. Why aren't there new controls used in windows 7 and office apps included in Visual Studio itself?

Comment: @dotNes, Visual Studio does contain ribbon controls and such, just not in the free Express version.

Comment: I didn't know that I actually have acces to the premium version of vs thanks to my college. I will definetly investigate that further. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use MFC (I don't), there is ribbon support:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354408.aspx.

Comment: Strange, mine was the only answer when I posted it, but now there's an answer that's older.